# React Native Expo error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing mobile app using React Native **expo**.. I am getting the following exception:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component....
```

I have gone through the other answers posted here on SO and have confirmed that the hook in my code is indeed inside a function. But still I am unable to resolve the error. KIndly help. Please see my code below. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Button, View, Platform , Text} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const statusBarPadding = Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight: 0;

export default function OpenGallery () {
   const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {      // hook is inside function but still getting error
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ paddingTop: statusBarPadding }}> 
        <Text> Some text </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );

}
```

Second file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Button, View, Platform , Text} from 'react-native';

import OpenGallery from './OpenGallery'
const statusBarPadding = Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight: 0;

export default function CameraScreen() {

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ paddingTop: statusBarPadding }}>
                <Text> Upload image from gallery.</Text>

        <Button title="Select from Gallery" onPress={OpenGallery} />
        </SafeAreaView>
        );

}
```

Comment: Error is triggered because of this fragment `onPress={OpenGallery}`. I am not sure what you would like to achieve, but you are calling functional component onPress action, it is not possible in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is in fact not being called from inside the component. you are calling it from the JSX, which is entirely different. there are two issues here that break the rules of hooks.

hooks must be called unconditionally. you are breaking that rule here.

```
<Button title="Select from Gallery" **onPress={OpenGallery}** />
```

Hooks must be called from inside a functional component. you cannot import another component and call it as a function. this is what you're doing. you are calling the react component on a onPress method which is wrong.

What can you do to fix it?
bring the state down. make the check to see if it's on a web or a mobile in the second file itself. i would post the code but i don't have expo installed at the moment.

Comment: OK Thanks. So how do I make it happen that - when I click a button it goes to a function component. And this function component contains a hook. How can I achieve this?

Comment: sadly it is not possible in react. you cannot call a react Functional component on a click. what you can do instead is run a useEffect() which checks which device it is, and based on that, decides whether to open the imagepicker or not.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound out of scope here but I think in your case, you need to specify the behaviour on how do you want the OpenGallery to appear after pressing the button on CameraScreen... you may be using navigation (may be react-navigation) or using a modal.

Let's say you're using react-navigation. (as you're using expo, it's normally included in the project) https://reactnavigation.org/

On CameraScreen

```js
export default function CameraScreen({navigation}) {
    const gotoOpenGallery = () => {
        navigation.navigate('OpenGallery');
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ paddingTop: statusBarPadding }}>
                <Text> Upload image from gallery.</Text>

        <Button title="Select from Gallery" onPress={gotoOpenGallery} />
        </SafeAreaView>
        );

}
```

You will also need to create a StackNavigator

Your App.js (or your entry point of the app)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import OpenGallery from './OpenGallery';
import CameraScreen from './CameraScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="CameraScreen" component={CameraScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OpenGallery" component={OpenGallery} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```